# Trying to run pygtk but I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError, despite following the attached steps, how can I add pygtk as a module?

Tags: python, pygtk, pygobject

I have just started learn how to use python so please forgive me if I come off as a beginner. The programming tool that I want to run requires PyGTK 2.7 or higher, and from what I figure the only way to run the pygtk module is to install msys2. I followed all of the steps up to step 7 in the link attached https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiorj.jpg), and I wasn't able to run the hello.py script they attached, despite successfully installing msys2 and updating the package database and core system packages. I keep getting the same error message when I try to run the code - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'". Afterwards, I tried running the programming tool anyway and I received a similar message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygtk'".

Answer (score 0):

PyGTK is deprecated and no longer being maintained. It hasn't been updated since 2011.

PyGObject is what replaced it. You won't be able to install PyGTK using the instructions you referenced.

You can install PyGTK still using:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python2-pygtk
```